# How can I tweak Knockout's writeable computed observeables to work with MVC model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a value for user display and a similar value for storage.  How can I modify what I have so that I save the correct data to the model?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/rS58T/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div>formatted value for user display</div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: formattedUnitOfCost" id="Model_Bound_ID" />

<div>unformatted value (the one I'd like to save)...this is not model bound</div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: unitOfCost" />
```

**JavaScript/Knockout**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

            self.unitOfCost = ko.observable(1.01).extend({
                isServerSet: false
            });
            self.formattedUnitOfCost = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    return '$' + self.unitOfCost().toFixed(2);
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
                    value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
                    self.unitOfCost(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
                },
                owner: self
            });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

The unformatted value is not displayed to the user.  `Model_Bound_ID` is user editable.

Comment: What do you mean on "model bound"? How do you send to data back to the server AJAX or with the built browser submit? Why don't you just put the unformated data in a hidden field: `<input type="hidden" name="yourC#proeprtyName" data-bind="value: unitOfCost" />`?

Comment: This field is tied to my model thats submitted on POST.  Ajax.  I would if I can tie that hidden field to my model instead of the visible field.  Im away from PC now, that might work.

Comment: @nemesv - yup you were right.  It was almost too easy.  That's the power of a genius that you must have no :P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way.

Your model bound control (I mean the control that will be posted to your controller, and has the unformatted value) should be created like any other control, for example using `Html.HiddenFor` or whatever you want in your (Razor?) template. And you must add the `data-bind` attribute in the template. Remember that low-dash will be converted in medium-dash, so you can add it in the attributes parameter of the Html Helper like this: `{ data_bind = "value: unitOfcost" }`.

Obviously this hidden field will be sent to the controller when posted (direct post, ajax, or whatever).

Now you need to add the visible control, and bind it to another observable. This observable will be a computed observable, which will do this:

- on read, it will take the value from `unitOfWork`, and return it formatted
- on write, it will parse the value to convert it to number, and update the `unitOfWork` observable with the parsed value

In fact you've got nearly all the code, but were implementing it all the way back.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this answer is to change the html from this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: formattedUnitOfCost" id="Model_Bound_ID" />    
<input type="text" data-bind="value: unitOfCost" />
```

to this

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: formattedUnitOfCost"/>    
<input type="text" data-bind="value: unitOfCost"  id="Model_Bound_ID"  />
```

And KO does the rest by the power of the observables.  Gosh I love KO